# Change hosts file on Jenkins executor node

Tags: cloudbees

We are planning to migrate our java web application build environment to Cloudbees but one aspect is currently blocking us.  We are developing a multi-tenant application. It uses host subdomain to identify tenants and we use wildcard dns entries to do that in production (e.g. : *.example.com).

In development, we have hardcoded a few entries in our hosts file to mimic that. Those entries are enough to run our tests :

```
...
127.0.0.1   test1.app.dev
127.0.0.1   test2.app.dev
127.0.0.1   test3.app.dev
127.0.0.1   test4.app.dev
```

So basically, Jenkins should set the hosts file, then launch our app using our web container locally. Then the test suite is executed against the running web app.

I tried to add a pre-process step in the Jenkins project configuration to edit the hosts file but as expected, the Jenkins job does not have permission to do that.

Is there a way to change the hosts file before my test suite is run? Or is there something else we could do to simulate wildcard dns entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the xip.io service from 37signals:

http://37signals.com/svn/posts/3191-announcing-pow-040-with-xipio-support

Thus your host names would be

- test1.127.0.0.1.xip.io
- test2.127.0.0.1.xip.io
- test3.127.0.0.1.xip.io
- test4.127.0.0.1.xip.io

I'd personally try and keep these in a centrally configured area, just in case the xip.io service was decommissioned, but it's probably fairly cheap to operate and so should be around for a while at least.

Comment: Nice! Did not know about that one. Thanks!